# mongodb date range issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My mongoose query is

```js
var filter = {
    changeDate: { $lte: toDate, $gte: fromDate }
};
changeLog.find(filter).sort('-changeDate').exec(function (err, _doc) {
    if (err) {
        logger.error(err);
        return res.status(400).send({ isSuccess: false, message: err, data: _doc });
    }
    return res.status(200).send({ isSuccess: true, message: err, data: result });
});
```

fromdate is 2/7/2016 and todate is 2/8/2016 . but I am getting record for only of 7th feb date not of 8th feb. Everytime code is taking todate as &lt not as &lte

In mongo changeDate is stored like 2016-02-01 07:49:29.084Z

Answer (score 1):

Your date range query is essentially looking for documents whose changeDate value fall in this range

```
ISODate("2016-02-07 00:00:00.000Z") <= changeDate <= ISODate("2016-02-08 00:00:00.000Z")
```

So for your query to filter 8th of Feb documents as well, consider changing your toDate to 9th of Feb so that it will pick from this range

```
ISODate("2016-02-07 00:00:00.000Z") <= changeDate < ISODate("2016-02-09 00:00:00.000Z")
```

e.g.

```
var toDate = new Date("2016-02-09"),
    fromDate = new Date("2016-02-07")
    filter = { "$gte": fromDate, "$lt": toDate };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but why query is not including 8th feb date records with operator $lte , I will increment the day by one and get the desired result but I want to know why it is behaving like this

Comment: @PriyeshTiwari Do you have documents in your collection where the changeDate is "2016-02-08 00:00:00.000Z"?

Comment: yes, here is one value of changeDate 2016-02-08 19:20:41.528Z , Suppose I am querying for dates b/w 7 to 9 th feb 2016, I am getting 7th feb and 8th feb records but not of 9th feb. I know if I increment 9th feb to 10th feb it will get the record of 9th feb also, I want to know why it is behaving like so , what wrong I am doing

Comment: @PriyeshTiwari I don't think you are getting it. "2016-02-08 00:00:00Z" is less than "2016-02-08 19:20:528Z" so when you use the query with toDate = 8 Feb 2016, MongoDB will fetch documents which have the changedDate less than "2016-02-08 00:00:00.000Z". I've even explained it clearly in the answer, where exactly are you missing the point?

Comment: @PriyeshTiwari I would put money on it that you are still constructing dates like `new Date("2/9/2016")` or similar but not `new Date("2016-02-09")` as is demonstrated. There is a difference in the constructor as to whether this is considered "local time" ( former ) or UTC ( the latter ). When comparing to UTC presented data you need to use UTC